# UICollectionView reloadData() crashes after emtying datasource dictionary

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which takes the results of an API search. The search is triggered by the following code. The results are appended to a dictionary `[[String: Any]]` and I call `self.collectionView.reloadData()` after my query completes.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var newValue = textField.text!
    let location = min(range.location, newValue.characters.count)
    let startIndex = newValue.characters.index(newValue.startIndex, offsetBy: location)
    let endIndex = newValue.characters.index(newValue.startIndex, offsetBy: location + range.length)
    let newRangeValue = Range<String.Index>(startIndex ..< endIndex)
    newValue.replaceSubrange(newRangeValue, with: string)

    searchView.searchFieldValueChanged(newValue)

    return true
}
```

Then, if I want to change the search string and search again I want to empty the dictionary and call reloadData() again I get an app crash.

The error is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:
```

Here is my datasource implementation

```
var searchResults = [[String: Any]]()


    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        layout.estimatedItemSize.height = 200
        layout.estimatedItemSize.width = 200
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        return layout
    }()

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(LanesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow // Constants.APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchResults.count == 0 {
        collectionView.alpha = 0.0
    } else {
            collectionView.alpha = 1.0
    }
    return searchResults.count
}
```

after query

```
func parseMoreData(jsonData: [String: Any]) {

    let items = jsonData["items"] as! [[String: Any]]

        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchFieldValueChanged(_ textValue: String) {

    searchResults = []
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of your `collectionView`'s `dataSource` implementation?

Comment: Instead of using the reloadData () try using reloadSections

Comment: Added extra code for datasource. There is only one section.

Comment: Are you adding your API responses to searchResults and notifying the collection view of new cells from within the main thread?

Comment: I believe so, I have not used any async threads except for Alamofire which uses an async thread internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fixed by using this instead of `layoutIfNeeded()`

```
 collectionView.reloadData()

 collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Comment: It worked for me, thank you.
Looks like this issue is fixed in iOS 11.